# importing datetimeoffset but the time is getting cut off

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I'm importing the following data into a sql server database:

[image]

For the dates I'm using this type:

[image]

(I've also tried DBTIMESTAMP). The same information can be seen in the data conversion properties:

[image]

When the data is actually imported, in the database it cuts the time component off:

[image]

**How do I retain the time component?**

**What type should I be storing in the database? datetimeoffset or datetime?**

When using it:

```
DECLARE @MyDatetimeoffset datetimeoffset(7)
```

What is the purpose of explicitly defining the length (7) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the datatype to DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP

Comment: What sort of type errors? Also, did you check this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899343/ssis-importing-datetime-column-into-sql-server-2008

Comment: im sorry i might be misunderstanding you. when you suggest to set the datatype you are saying in both the settings of the connection and the transformation?

Comment: i did try to play with all of those settings, and right now the records are just coming in with NULL for the datetime.

Comment: Do you actually need datetimeOffset, or do just want to import the data as datetime? I see you have other attributes defined as datetime, so I presume you know the difference... What is the datatype for these fields in the actual database?

Comment: in the target database, i've tried both offset and regular datetime, it only worked when i was reading in as datetimeoffset and having the target defined as datetimeoffset. i want to import the data as DATETIME